# CSS is affecting all pages, but I just want to use it for one

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have created the following CSS for my login screen but `.cssbox, input[type=text]:focus` CSS is affecting all text boxes on all the different pages.

I just want to use it for the login page.

I have one style sheet theme for all pages:

```
.cssbox 
{
    border: solid 1px #C3D9E0;
    background-color: #eeeeff;
    background-image: url(/images/console-bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    /*width: 460px;*/
    margin-left: 30%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 4px;
    /*border-radius: 4px;*/
}

.cssbox, input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus, 
    textarea:focus, select:focus
{
    border-color: #66afe9;
    outline: 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #95B8E7;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #95B8E7;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #95B8E7;
}


<table class="cssbox" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" 
    border="0" width="398px" style="height: 287px;margin:0 auto;">

    <tr style="height: 22px">
         <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" 
                runat="server" type="text" placeholder="Username" 
                CssClass="cssbox-input-text"></asp:TextBox>        
         </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: just change to `input[type=text].cssbox:focus`. This will target only those `input`s that have the class `cssbox` and are focused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want the css to be applied only inside .cssbox, so you have to modify your css like this:

```
.cssbox input[type=text]:focus,
.cssbox input[type=password]:focus,
.cssbox textarea:focus,
.cssbox select:focus   
{
   border-color: #66afe9;
   outline: 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #95B8E7;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #95B8E7;
   box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #95B8E7;
 }
```

Comment: one more question, how can i define custom css for jqery UI within cssbox on login page? At the moment i am using CssClass="ui-corner-all ui-corner-all hover", it is working but effecting other pages.

Comment: If you want jqueryUI to affect only login page, instantiate only there! Please accept an answer if it helped you you to solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to add a class to the body tag ONLY on your login page, i.e.:

```
<body class="login-page">
    ....
</body>
```

Then change the CSS selectors from

```
.cssbox, input[type=text]:focus
```

to

```
.login-page .cssbox, .login-page input[type=text]:focus
```

So it's the same matching criteria, except that those elements must be children of an element with the login-page class (which you've only applied to the body tag of the login page).

EDIT: The other answers have a good point - the selectors you have chosen appear incorrect. If that's the case then this answer doesn't really apply...

Answer (score 0):

Is `class="cssbox"` unique to the login page?

If so, you need to specify your `input[type=text]:focus` like so:

```
.cssbox input[type=text]:focus {

...

}
```

If you need the same box-shadow and border styles to apply to `.cssbox` and the `input[type=text]:focus` it contains, then you need:

```
.cssbox, .cssbox input[type=text]:focus {

...

}
```